# "blob:http: ... " what is it? and how to save it to a file?

Tags: javascript, php

I tried to explain more my issue but I guess it will be easier with some words and without my dirty code:

What is this and how can I put it in a file in my public folder?

blob:http://127.0.0.1/268ea876-5179-4a94-955c-7a191f8f84b5

I got this as a result this when uploading a GPX file.
I tried to make it a blob file (with vuejs) to then put it in a file (with php) but or it is empty, or it just contains the text "blob: http://....". No way to get the content of this file.

If I put it in the browser, the content is showing well.

Thanks a lot, I hope my question is more clear here :)

Comment: It's a Blob URL... a temporary resource that is created in-browser by some JavaScript.  Yes, you can open it in a new tab even if you want, but it won't stay there forever.  It isn't clear from your question what it is that you're trying to do.  Sounds like you just want to link to it to download it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is a Blob?**

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data. Blobs represent data that isn't necessarily in a JavaScript-native format. The File interface is based on Blob, inheriting blob functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system.
>
> To construct a Blob from other non-blob objects and data, use the Blob() constructor. To create a blob that contains a subset of another blob's data, use the slice() method. To obtain a Blob object for a file on the user's file system, see the File documentation.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

**How to save it to a file?**

Look at the Filereader documentation in the official specification.

See: https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader

**Practical (simplified) implementation**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const Image = ({ fileOrBlob }) => {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => { loadFileOrBlob (fileOrBlob) }}, [])

  const loadFileOrBlob = file => {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    if (file.name === undefined) return
    reader.addEventListener('load', () => setSrc(reader.result))

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }

  return src 
    ? <img alt="" src={src} className={styles.image} /> 
    : <span>[<em> Loading image... </em>]</span>
}
```

**Save it in PHP to store it into a file**

Probably you're using some library that creates this blob. In order to save it, your server-side code has to receive the actual data from the blob and store it into a file. Most libraries do this using an ajax request. There are some decent implementations shown as examples of Dropzone.js.

See for example: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation